# What do "orbits" look like?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-forms, linear-groups

I recently learned about the set
$$\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)=\left\{\left({{a\quad b}\atop{c\quad d}}\right)\in\Bbb Z^{2\times 2}:ad-bc=1\right\}$$
where $\Bbb Z^{2\times 2}$ is the set of $2$ by $2$ integer matrices. I also learned of the set $$\Bbb H=\{z\in\Bbb C:\text{Im }z>0\}.$$
Then I learned of a set called the "orbit" of some $z\in\Bbb H$:
$$\text{orb }z=\left\{\frac{az+b}{cz+d}:\left({{a\quad b}\atop{c\quad d}}\right)\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)\right\}.$$
I have tried to visualize what $\text{orb }z$ looks like in the complex plane using Desmos, but Desmos does not really do complex numbers, and finding members of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$ is a little hard for me.

> So, what do "orbits" look like? Does anyone have anything which I can use to visualize them? Thanks.

Comment: There are just points on the upper complex plane... You can though read about Fundamental Domain and etc., which is basic and elementary for Modular Forms.

Comment: in a general group, the orbit of an element looks like all of the elements you can 'get to' from that element. See e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Orbits_and_stabilizers) or [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupOrbit.html)

Comment: @graeme and there aren't any pretty pictures or nice visualizations for this particular case?

Comment: The "picture" of the orbit depends of the point z you take. If you take $z=0$ (which is at the border of the upper halfplane) you get all rational numbers.

Comment: Here you have a picture of the fundamental domains https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ModularGroup-FundamentalDomain-01.png#/media/File:ModularGroup-FundamentalDomain-01.png

Comment: Yes, there are very nice pictures. Try here, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain Also, many good books on modular forms have pretty similar pics.

Comment: The group $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $T=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ (translation) and $S= \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ (inversion and rotation). The fundamental domain $\mathcal{F}$ of this group is $\{ z \in \mathbb{H} \ | \ |z| > 1 \text{ and } |\mathrm{Re}(z) |< 1/2 \}$, i.e., no two points in this set lie in the same orbit and every point in $\mathbb{H}$ is the image of some point in the closure of $\mathcal{F}$. You can focus your attention on $\mathcal{F}$ and see what happens to the points in it under the action of the above matrices.